# Deserializing Composite Objects in Java

Tags: java, deserialization

I have a question regarding deserializing composite objects. My object looks as follows:

```
public class Outside
{
   private String str1;
   private Inside s;
}

public class Inside
{
   private String str2;
   public Inside(String str2) 
   {
    this.field1 = str2;
   }
}
```

when I want to deserialize the response to Json

```
Outside o = wr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(Outside .class);
```

I get the following exception
....ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class Outside, and Java type class Outside, and MIME media type application/json was not found

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you mean `private Inside s;` instead of `private Second s;`? This looks more like a JAX-RS (Jersey Client?) issue than a deserialization issue.

Comment: It works when it is not a composite object. So I guessed it should be related to de-serialization.

Comment: It certainly isn't a deserialisation issue, as it doesn't require a no-args constructor.

Comment: @bizclop - I don't agree with your statement (or maybe I just don't understand your wording). I think it IS a deserialization issue caused by the `Inside` class not having a default constructor.

Comment: @JesseWebb The word "serialization" is ambiguous here. Java's serialization framework and any libraries utilising it (like XStream) work fine without no-args constructors. Let's call this an unmarshalling problem and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ....Inside.()

This is referring to a constructor of the form `Inside()`, which you don't have - you've only got `Inside(String)`.  Serialization requires a no-argument constructor so it can easily use reflection to instantiate your object, and then fill in the fields.

Thus, you need to add a no-arg constructor.

Comment: @user1558274: Ahh, yes, then it appears to be a different problem!